# Filter people picker

Tags: sharepoint, filter

I have some customer sites and I have a issue list with a people picker. I want to show only the people that have access to the customer site of their own company. I don't want that other customers see customers of a other company.

I tried this but it doesn't have any effect:

```
stsadm -o setproperty –url http://extranet.company.com/sites/project1 –pn peoplepicker-onlysearchwithinsitecollection –pv yes
```

Comment: Oops, sorry, didn't read the tags correctly, my answer was therefore completely off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

The stsadm command  peoplepicker-onlysearchwithinsitecollection will only show people that are members of that site collection, a better way to restrict the users would be to use the stsadm command:

[peoplepicker-searchadcustomfilter](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263452.aspx)

so:

stsadm -o setproperty -url http://contoso -pn peoplepicker-searchadcustomfilter -pv (LDAP QUERY)

This lets you specify an LDAP Query, which can be made to return any AD users or groups based on any criteria that you wish.

Comment: does it works for subsites to? i want to filter in a subsite only users that have access to the subsite.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, [peoplepicker-**searchadcustomfilter**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263452.aspx) applies to the entire web application, even if I specify a site collection in the URL parameter.

```
stsadm –o setproperty –propertyname peoplepicker-searchadcustomfilter -propertyvalue "(|(userPrincipalName=*mycompany.com)(memberof=CN=client_users,OU=client_Users,OU=Extranet,DC=client,DC=int))" -url http://myserver/sites/site1 

stsadm -o getproperty -pn peoplepicker-searchadcustomfilter -url http://myserver/sites/site1
stsadm -o getproperty -pn peoplepicker-searchadcustomfilter -url http://myserver/sites/site2
```

When I ran the above, I expected to see site1 with the custom LDAP query, and site2 with no filter applied.  But instead I see the custom LDAP query on all site collections in this web application.  Bummer.

Looks like Microsoft needs to clarify the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263452.aspx).